# Could I use Processing.py to display text and shapes on a Waveshare ePaper display?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python-3, raspberry-pi-desktop, eink

I am new to Raspberry Pi and programming in general. I have very basic knowledge on Processing.py and I would like to know is it possible I could use this library to display shapes and text on a waveshare ePaper display?

Considering one of their demos uses python 3?

I couldn't find anything on the internet regarding this subject and was wondering if anyone here has any experience in using a Waveshare ePaper display and processing.py .

Comment: I googled and found the following: 
Waveshare 800x600, 4.3inch e-Paper UART Module - $57
(1) https://www.waveshare.com/4.3inch-e-paper.htm
(2) https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/4.3inch_e-Paper_UART_Module I found the module compatible with Windows and Arduino UART.  Document detailed for making images and reading English and Chinese fonts. UART used is the commonly used, with simple interface commands.  I know UART devices pretty well and once played with similar graphics LCD modules with Chinese fonts using SPI.  I guess an average Rpi/Arduino hobbyist would think Rpi python 3 can do the job.

Comment: The user manual is also good, suggesting which UART to serial cable to use: WaveShare 4.3inch e-Paper User Manual： https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/7/71/4.3inch-e-Paper-UserManual.pdf